# Request for improvement suggestion on my CNN learning model?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

I’m trying to build a classification model for production line. If I understand correctly , it’s possible to use a CNN to classify numerical data .(and not only pictures)

My data is an array of 21 columns  per line:
20 different measurements and the last column is a type . It can be 0 or 1 or 2
each line of the array use a timestamp as index

type 0 represents 80 % of the production, and do not need extra treatment 
but type 1 and 2 need extra treatment after production (*so I need to clearly identify them*)

To recreate something a CNN can use , I created a dataset where each label has for learning data an array made of the last previous 20 lines  since it’s position .
So each label has for corresponding learning data ,  a square array of 20x20 measurements (like a picture ) .
(data already have been normalized using keras ColumnTransformer

after reading about unbalanced dataset , i decided to include only a type 0 each time I found a type 1 or 2 . At the end my dataset size is 18 000 lines , **data shape  '(18206, 20, 20)'**

my learning model is pretty basic and looks like this :

```
        train, test, train_label, test_label = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,shuffle=True)
        ##Call CNN model
        sizePic = 20
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(sizePic*3, input_shape=(sizePic,sizePic,), activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(sizePic, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
        # Compile model
        sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.03)
        model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
        self.logger.info(model.summary())

        # Fit the model
        model.fit(train, train_label, epochs=750, batch_size=200,verbose=1)
        # evaluate the model
        self.learning_scores = model.evaluate(test, test_label, verbose=2)
        self.logger.info("scores %r"%self.learning_scores)
```

at the end prediction scores are :

scores [0.6088506683505354, 0.7341632843017578]

I have been changing parameters like batch_size and learning rate , but with no big improvement . To my understanding, it's better to start this way than adding layers to the model , is this correct ? 
Any suggestion ?? 
thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using any conv layer, only fully connected layers (and don't be afraid of adding some conv layers because they have way less parameters than dense layers)